# How can I earn the Resolution hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

[image]

1. Do the comments I delete need to be mine?
2. How can I find 10 comments to delete to earn the Resolution hat?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 1. Do the comments I delete need to be mine?

UPDATE: Yes the comments need to be yours. (*unclear if this applies to diamond mods*)

<s>The hat doesn't specify if the comments need to be yours. Users can delete their own comments, but most users can't delete other people's comments. They have to flag the comment and then a moderator needs to choose to delete the comment. So it's unclear as of yet if getting 10 helpful flags for 10 comment flag deletion requests is sufficient. According to a [higher-up](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2779589#2779589) though, it looks like they might not need to be your comments.</s>

> 2. How can I find 10 comments to delete to earn the Resolution hat?

You can go through your old comments by going to your profile page, click on *activity*, click on *comments*. It's good to delete your not constructive/obsolete/rude or offensive/too chatty comments on a regular basis anyways, but if you want to make sure your deletions count towards the Resolution Hat, make sure that the comments you delete were posted in 2014. If you prefer to use SEDE, you can simply type your `UserId` into the text box and run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259846/testt) to find the comments you left in 2014 for a particular site.

*On a side note: Please help the sites stay clean by flagging other people's not constructive/too chatty/rude/obsolete comments on a regular basis. To find other peoples' comments to flag for deletion you can normally find not constructive/too chatty comments just by browsing questions/answers like you normally do, and flag them if they fit one of the flag reasons. Or you could run a query like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259849/comments-like-accept-rate-acceptance-rate-accepting-in-2014) or [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/230638/test) or [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/259853/last-year-comments-like-what-have-you-tried-where-an-accepted-answer-is-present?CommentThread=4)<sub>([Stack Overflow only](http://stackoverflow.com))</sub> to search for not constructive/too chatty comments that should be deleted.*

<sub>Please note that the linked queries are searching [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), so to search another site just type in the site name in the Switch Sites input box to search another SE site.</sub>

Comment: Might be that the comments have to to upvoted first, so I've forked the query: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/259850/user-1-comments-for-2014

Comment: @Shadow Eh that's doubtful. The implicit quality requirements are generally reserved for content you're contributing. It would seem kind of silly to restrict this one and encourage users to only delete upvoted comments, when the non-upvoted ones have better chances of needing deletion.

Comment: "January 1st 2015 UTC time" - Does the buffer time apply? (totally not seeding pointless comments to delete next year)

Comment: @animuson good point. Well, I've also improved the query a bit by using DatePart. ;)

Comment: Congrats on your Selfie hat! ;)

Comment: lol, now thanks to @ProgramFOX I see the real motive behind this question! ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but that's nonsense. Of course they have to be your own comments. It's a new years hat that is called "resolution" after all.

Comment: @balpha "As a moderator, be better about cleaning up chatty comments on my site" isn't a resolution? :-)

Comment: I've just discovered that you don't have to delete them all yourself; it's enough to *have them deleted* whether by yourself or by mods.